# Authentication mysql to .Net

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, database

I have **Mysql** DB connected to **.NET MVC**. When i connect remote it some times works fine and some times i have this error msg:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Authentication to
>   host 'ServerName' for user 'UserName' using method
>   'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Reading from the stream
>   has failed. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005):
>   Reading from the stream has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable
>   to read data from the transport connection: An established connection
>   was aborted by the software in your host machine. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was
>   aborted by the

Please how can i make Authentication ? Any ideas to solve it?

Comment: It would help if you give some code example.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error when some kind of deadlock occurs on the database more commonly a connection has been open a long time and gets shut down at the database end even though it is still in-use in your web application.

In my code, I used a suggestion from Microsoft, that retries the database command if it fails. The link is here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4235.retry-logic-for-transient-failures-in-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx Similar things exist for other non-Azure problems that use RetryPolicy.

What this means in a simple (Azure in my case) example is:

```
private static RetryPolicy<SqlAzureTransientErrorDetectionStrategy> retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<SqlAzureTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(new Incremental(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));


// Inside your database function  
retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() =>
{
    db.ExecuteStoredProc("procRecordMetric", cmd);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was caused by ssl being enabled on the mysql server.

Here is a snippet from my.cnf

```
#ssl-ca          = /etc/ssl/mysql/ca-cert.pem
#ssl-cert        = /etc/ssl/mysql/server-cert.pem
#ssl-key         = /etc/ssl/mysql/server-key.pem
```

Commenting these 3 lines fixed the issue for me.